# Change the environment for creating a WordPress page

Tags: pages

I tried WordPress this time, and the YouTube screen and my page development environment are very different. How do I set it up like the second screen?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use classic-editor and a page builder for building the page.

plugins->add new search name and install plugin and activate it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/page+builder/

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I was able to solve it.

Comment: mark my answer as accepted.